# Group lists by final item, but keep order

Tags: python, list

I have a list-of-lists, `Corp`. It looks like this:

```
list-of-lists = [
['the\tthe Def Det  _1', '_1']
['dogs\tdog N Sg @SUBJ>  _1', '_1']
['bark\tmiskan V 3Sg @PRED  _1', '_1']
['.\t? CLB  _1', '_1']
['it\tit Pron 3Sg @SUBJ>  _2', '_2']
['scared\tscare V Pst @PRED  _2', '_2']
['me\tI Pron 1Sg @OBJ<  _2', '_2']
...
]
```

What I want to do is group these so all items with the same sentence index (the final item in each list is grouped, like so:

```
[
[['the\tthe Def Det  _1', '_1'],
['dogs\tdog N Sg @SUBJ>  _1', '_1'],
['bark\tmiskan V 3Sg @PRED  _1', '_1'],
['.\t? CLB  _1', '_1']]

[['it\tit Pron 3Sg @SUBJ>  _2', '_2'],
['scared\tscare V Pst @PRED  _2', '_2'],
['me\tI Pron 1Sg @OBJ<  _2', '_2']]
...
]
```

I have tried using `itemgetter` and `groupby` from the operator and itertools modules (respectively). The issue with this is that they see, to reorder the embedded new list-of-lists:

```
groupedcorp = [[x for x,y in g]
       for k,g in  groupby(splitcorp,key=itemgetter(1))]
```

```
[
[['.\t? CLB  _1', '_1']],
['dogs\tdog N Sg @SUBJ>  _1', '_1'],
['bark\tmiskan V 3Sg @PRED  _1', '_1'],
['the\tthe Def Det  _1', '_1']]

[['scared\tscare V Pst @PRED  _2', '_2'],
[['it\tit Pron 3Sg @SUBJ>  _2', '_2'],
['me\tI Pron 1Sg @OBJ<  _2', '_2']]
...
]
```

I'm fine with the final sentence index being eaten up (the second item in each atomic list.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please share your code, that's reordering the elements. `groupby` should not be reordering anything.

Comment: And a question: Are the instances of each final item next to each other, as in your example (so that you only need to group consecutive elements), or are they sometimes interleaved?

Comment: There should always only be two items in each of the embedded lists, and the second item is always the sentence index.

Comment: This won't really solve your current problem, but I suggest you use a more appropriate data structure than a list of lists here. For example, create a class to hold the items then create a list of class objects. This will help you to reason about your code more easily.

Comment: Also a dict or a list of dict would be two other options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand the question (not 100% sure..). The below is the grouping you are looking for.

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = defaultdict(list)

lists = [['the\tthe Def Det  _1', '_1'],
         ['dogs\tdog N Sg @SUBJ>  _1', '_1'],
         ['bark\tmiskan V 3Sg @PRED  _1', '_1'],
         ['.\t? CLB  _1', '_1'],
         ['it\tit Pron 3Sg @SUBJ>  _2', '_2'],
         ['scared\tscare V Pst @PRED  _2', '_2'],
         ['me\tI Pron 1Sg @OBJ<  _2', '_2']

         ]
for lst in lists:
    data[lst[-1]].append(lst)
for k,v in data.items():
    print(f'{k} -> {v}')
```

output

```
_1 -> [['the\tthe Def Det  _1', '_1'], ['dogs\tdog N Sg @SUBJ>  _1', '_1'], ['bark\tmiskan V 3Sg @PRED  _1', '_1'], ['.\t? CLB  _1', '_1']]
_2 -> [['it\tit Pron 3Sg @SUBJ>  _2', '_2'], ['scared\tscare V Pst @PRED  _2', '_2'], ['me\tI Pron 1Sg @OBJ<  _2', '_2']]
```

Comment: Turns out, my original code was working fine, but the puctuation was simply being applied to the wrong sentence in the first place...

Still, I like dictionaries better. Thanks